# Is there any way to access child method from parent component when mounting in Vue.js 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, mount, ref, vuejs3

Could you teach me how to access child function from the parent component when mounting in VueJS?

I have attached the sample code to make this problem clear.

P.S.
I have added the child component and some code to the parent one.
You can see the codes below.

```html
<template>
  <div>Child</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Child",
  setup() {
    const childFunc = () => {
      console.log('This is Child.');
    };
  
    return {
      childFunc
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from "@vue/composition-api";
import Child from "./Child.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Parent",
  components: {
    Child
  },
  setup() {
    const child = ref();

    onMounted(() => {
      child.value.childFunc(); // Error: childFunc of undefined 
    });

    return {
      child
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <Child ref="child" />
</template>
```

Comment: how do you define the `Child` component?

Comment: I defined the child component as the parent one.

Comment: please share it

Comment: you can see it above

Answer (score 1):

It should work, in the following example i created a child component with button that increments a count, this count in mounted is incremented by parent by one :

```js
const {
  createApp,
  ref,
  onMounted,
  defineComponent
} = Vue

let Child = defineComponent({
  name: "Child",
    setup() {
    const childFunc = () => {
      console.log('This is Child.');
    };
  
    return {
      childFunc
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++;
    }
  },
  template: `
    <button @click="count++">
      You clicked me {{ count }} times.
    </button>`
})
let app = createApp({
  el: '#app',
  setup() {
    const child = ref();

    onMounted(() => {
 child.value.childFunc(); 
      child.value.increment()
    });

    return {
      child
    };
  },
  components: {
    Child
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  test
  <Child ref="child" />
</div>
```

Comment: Really... thank you for your report. I will try to find some problems. And also I would like to add that I could find "child" in the onMounted function. However, I couldn't find "child.value" in it.

Comment: try to log `child` in mounted hook like `console.log(child)` and give me the output

Comment: This is the result. RefImpl {value: (...)get value: ƒ ()set value: ƒ (v)__proto__: Object}

Comment: it works you could check my edited answer where i use the same logic as you did

Comment: It doesn't work correctly, but if I use setTimeout(), I could access it perfectly.

Comment: how do you do this with vue 2 & Composition API?

Answer (score 0):

I feel obliged to ask: are you sure you want to do this? A function is just a dumb function, not reactive. How do you envisage the separation between your components? Vue components work best when they interact with a store, and so have the fewest possible links between them. The parent-child relationship just refers to DOM placement, which may change over time. `ref` is one of those features where you should ask yourself 'do I really need to do this?'

Comment: Yes you're right, Vue encourages the data driven process

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I needed to access a child component's function, so handled with this problem using the setTimeOut function. Could you give me some examples of your solution? That would be appreciated.